# How to remove failure using fuel with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make communication program using fuel in Kotlin.

This code is successful(I/System.out:Success)

```
"http://google.com/".httpGet().responseString
{ request, response, result ->
    when (result) {
        is Result.Success -> println("Success")
        is Result.Failure -> println("Failure")
    }
}
```

On the other hands, this code is failure(I/System.out:Failure)

```
"http://google.com/".httpPost().responseString
{ request, response, result ->
    when (result) {
        is Result.Success -> println("Success")
        is Result.Failure -> println("Failure")
    }
}
```

Do you have any solutions to succeed httpPost()? 
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

method `post` is not allowed by Google website. Check the logs of failure:

```
[Failure: HTTP Exception 405 Method Not Allowed]
```